# Raising a trigger when a file is downloaded in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, power-automate

How can I detect when a file is downloaded from SharePoint Online? I need this to send a disclaimer when it occurs.
I find next to zero results on this topic :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no such trigger which detects when a file is download in Power Automate World. You can share your ideas here: [Power Automate Ideas](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/idb-p/MPAIdeas). It is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft Power Automate products. What's more, if a feedback is high voted there by other customers, it will be promising that Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.